# Vue computed property updates without dependency change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a computed property to sort a Javascript object alphabetically by key. I added logging to the computed property to make sure that it was not being invoked without a dependency change.

I found that without changing the reactive dependency (`sensorData`), the computed property seems to reevaluate at a high rate (10+ Hz).

Why is it reevaluating without a dependency change?

### What I've Tried

I know that Vue recommends against property addition/deletion, and my object is initialized to `{}`. However, even when initializing it with every key, I had the same result.

I also tried `vm.$set(object, key, value)` [as recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) if properties need to be added after a page is rendered. No luck.

#### JSON from Server

```json
{
  "readings": {
    "stepperC": 180,
    "stepperA": 360,
    "stepperB": 0
  }
}
```

#### Vue Code

```js
data: () => ({
  sensorData: {}
}),
computed: {
  // sort alphabetically by key
  sortedSensorData() {
    console.log("calling sort");
    return Object.keys(this.sensorData).sort()
      .reduce((obj, key) => ({
        ...obj,
        [key]: this.sensorData[key]
      }), {});
  }
}
methods: {
  handleWebSocketMessage({ data }) {
    const newReadings = data.readings;
    if (Object.entries(newReadings).some(([sensor, reading]) => this.sensorData[sensor] !== reading))
      this.sensorData = newReadings;
  }
}
```

#### Output

With no change to `sensorData`:

```
calling sort
calling sort
calling sort
...
```

Comment: Where did you defined `this.reading`? There is only a `sensorData` in your data; is `reading` a prop?

Comment: @mo3n That was a mistake. Updated to `sensorData`

Comment: You're not showing the actual cause of the bug, which makes your question unanswerable. Please create a *runnable* [mcve] (use codesandbox.io or similar), making sure the bug is reproduced.

Comment: Also, I hope you're aware in JavaScript sorting the object properties by key is futile, as JS does not guarantee maintaining their order. While it might work in a browser, it might not work in another. And while it might work today, it might not work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think in `(obj, key)` what you've calling `obj` is actually a *key* in the object

Try logging the value of `Object.keys(...)` before returning it